# .emacs.desktop file destroyed by custom function

Tags: emacs, dot-emacs

I use the Emacs desktop module to save my open buffers between sessions. However I found that this accumulates more buffers than I want, so I wrote a small function to clean up the buffer list immediately before saving to the desktop file. This works as expected, but for strange reasons the .emacs.desktop gets scrambled occasionally, i.e. it contains a part of another buffer at its start, then the intended contents and then the result of the other buffer. I don't have the slightest idea, why this happens. Here is an excerpt from my .emacs file:

```
(defun kill-old-buffers ()
  "Kill buffers from end of buffer list (not used recently) until no more than 50 buffers are left. Remove temporary buffers first"
  (interactive)
  (let* (desktop-buffer (current-buffer))
   (dolist (buffer (buffer-list))
     (if (or (string-match "^\*" (buffer-name buffer)) (string-match "\.hpp$" (buffer-name buffer)))
         (kill-buffer buffer)
       )
     )

  (setq all-buffers (reverse (buffer-list)))
  (while (> (safe-length all-buffers) 50)
    (setq buffer (pop all-buffers))
    (if (not (string-equal (buffer-name buffer) (buffer-name (current-buffer))))
        (kill-buffer buffer)
      )
    )
  (switch-to-buffer desktop-buffer)
))

;; Kill old rarely-used buffers before saving
(add-hook 'desktop-save-hook
  '(lambda () (kill-old-buffers)))
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure if your function is really the cause of your problem. If it should be the case, the wrong usage of the `let*` that scottfrazer pointed out might be the cause. But you don't even need that `let*` (and `switch-to-buffer`) at all, because

1. what you're trying to do is better done with Emacs' built in `save-excursion`, and
2. you aren't actually switching the buffer ever.

OTOH, you should have used `let` instead of the `setq`s in the lower half of your function, because `setq` will otherwise change a variable from an enclosing lexical scope. In this case you might very well have stomped over a `buffer` variable from the function that's executing the `desktop-save-hook` which is another potential cause of your problem.

But you don't need those `let`s either because you can do the second loop with another `dolist`. You can get rid of those first 50 buffers that you don't want to loop over with `nthcdr`.

Here's my improved version of `kill-old-buffers`:

```
(defun kill-old-buffers ()
  "Kill buffers from end of buffer list (not used recently) until
no more than 50 buffers are left. Remove temporary buffers first."
  (interactive)
  (save-excursion
    (dolist (buffer (buffer-list))
      (if (or (string-match "^\*" (buffer-name buffer))
              (string-match "\.hpp$" (buffer-name buffer)))
          (kill-buffer buffer)))

    (dolist (buffer (reverse (nthcdr 50 (buffer-list))))
      (unless (eq buffer (current-buffer))
        (kill-buffer buffer)))))
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. Lisp is not my primary programming language, as you already may have guessed ;-) I have replaced my version with yours, but only time will tell, if this ends my occasional problems. I will report, if this happened again in a week or two.

Comment: Just a short update after three weeks of experience with your solution: It seems to work without problems now, though I still don't understand, what caused the original problems. Thanks a lot again.

Answer (score 0):

It may not fix all your problems, but for starters you need another set of parens around the variable in your `let*` statement

```
(let* ((desktop-buffer (current-buffer)))
```